# Weird behaviour of Queue.empty in Python

Tags: python, queue, python-multiprocessing

I came across this weird issue with multiprocessing's Queue.empty() in Python. The following code output is True and 20, right after filling it with elements.

```
from multiprocessing import Queue
import random

q = Queue()
for _ in range(20):
    q.put(random.randint(0, 2))
#time.sleep(0.01)
print(q.empty())
print(q.qsize())
```

If I uncomment the sleep, the output is correct: False, 20. How is this possible? This code *should* run sequentially, which means by the time the q.empty() evaluates, the queue is already filled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You can't rely on the result from a call to `multiprocessing.Queue.empty()`.

The documentation for `.empty()` states:

> Return `True` if the queue is empty, `False` otherwise. **Because of multithreading/multiprocessing semantics, this is not reliable.**

The documentation also states that a separate thread handles queuing objects, causing the observed behavior:

> When an object is put on a queue, the object is pickled and a background thread later flushes the pickled data to an underlying pipe. This has some consequences which are a little surprising, but should not cause any practical difficulties – if they really bother you then you can instead use a queue created with a manager.
>
> **After putting an object on an empty queue there may be an infinitesimal delay before the queue’s `empty()` method returns False** and `get_nowait()` can return without raising queue.Empty.

You have a single process, so use the queue from the `Queue` module, which does not rely on another thread to add the data to the queue:

```py
from queue import Queue
import random

q = Queue()
for _ in range(20):
    q.put(random.randint(0, 2))
print(q.empty())
print(q.qsize())
```

If you must use multiple processes, you should try to restructure your code to rely on `.empty()` as little as possible, because its results are unreliable. For example, instead of using `.empty()` to check whether there are elements on the queue, you should simply attempt to pop off the queue and block if there aren't any elements.

Comment: I have to use multiprocessing, so I'll go for the .get() + exception handling for queue.Empty. Thanks.

Comment: Note that you don't need exception handling here: `q.get()` _blocks_ until something appears on the queue.

Answer (score 1):

The output isn't deterministic, with or without the `sleep()`. The part you *see* runs sequentially, but, under the covers, `q.put(thing)` hands `thing` off to a `multiprocessing` worker thread to do the actual work of mutating the queue. `.put()` returns at once then, regardless of whether the worker thread has managed to put `thing` on the queue yet.

This can burn you "for real"! For example, consider this program:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

q = mp.Queue()
nums = list(range(20))
q.put(nums)
# time.sleep(2)
del nums[-15:]
print(q.get())
```

Chances are that it will display:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

This is so even if some other process retrieves from `q`. `q.put(nums)` hands off the task of pickling `nums`, and putting its serialized form on the queue, and  there's a race between that and the main program mutating `nums`.

If you uncomment the `sleep(2)`, then chances are high that it will display the original 20-element `nums` instead.